# How to capture cursor movements and key strokes on a Mac (in the entire system)?

Tags: macos, keystroke, keylogger

maybe you know the program Keyboard Maestro for Mac. With Keyboard Maestro you can call Scripts by pressing custom keyboard shortcuts and you can listen for text input (e.g. you can create a ⌘ every time you type "cmd"...) no matter which app is running.

How can I recreate this behavior in my app (which runs in the background)? It seems impossible to reproduce with Node.js or AppleScript alone, so I think I have to use C++ or Obj-C. Am I right? But I have no experience with one of these. Are there any tutorials?
It can't be this hard or? I just want a system wide "on(keyPress, callback)". Nothing more.

Thank you,
Pipo

Answer (score 3):

I think I found it myself?

You have at least two options. You can use "addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler" from the NSEvent Class (Cocoa), but it can't handle some keystrokes (specific system shortcuts, etc.). It is more "high level" and read only.
The "low level" solution has read-write ability and detects more keystrokes. It uses CGEventTaps (Quartz). You can found an example here: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200503003001/http://osxbook.com/book/bonus/chapter2/alterkeys/).